# Showing message on cart table(above each product.message will change based on qty) in WooCommerce cart page

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'bbloomer_split_cart_by_az', 9999 );

function bbloomer_split_cart_by_az(){

        if ( ! is_cart() ) return; 

       if ( WC()->cart->is_empty() ) return;

       $i = 0;

       $split = array();

       foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {

          $cart_item_title = $cart_item['data']->get_title();

          $first_letter = substr( $cart_item_title, 0, 1 );

          if ( 0 == $i || ( 0 < $i && ! in_array( $first_letter, $split ) ) ) {

    if($cart_item['quantity'] == 2) {

     $split[$i] = 'custom message'

    }
          }
          $i++;
       }
       ?>
       <script type="text/javascript">

          jQuery(document).ready(function($){

             var indx = $('.woocommerce-cart-form__contents tbody tr').length;

             var rows = <?php echo json_encode($split); ?>;

             $.each(rows,function(key,value){   

                var newRow = $('<tr><td colspan="6">'+value+'</td></tr>');

                   newRow.insertBefore($('.woocommerce-cart-form__contents tbody tr.woocommerce-cart-form__cart-item:nth('+key+')'));

             });

          });

       </script>

       <?php  

    }
```

[See screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lO8Xc.png)

https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-split-cart-table-az-headings/ - I have used this hook,

This is showing alphabet something, but my message dynamically changed when qty changes made.

when the total cart page is refreshed message is showing properly, if u adding one qty of any product then WordPress default ajax will load to update total and etc. After that, my message is not showing. I am thinking to add any hook that will trigger after ajax loaded the new qty and cart total so that jquery will add the new tr td with my message any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy this code to your active theme folder `/woocommerce/cart.php`. Template overriding is the best option for this.

```
<?php
/**
 * Cart Page
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/cart/cart.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see     https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @package WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version 3.8.0
 */

defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;

do_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart' ); ?>

<form class="woocommerce-cart-form" action="<?php echo esc_url( wc_get_cart_url() ); ?>" method="post">
    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart_table' ); ?>

    <table class="shop_table shop_table_responsive cart woocommerce-cart-form__contents" cellspacing="0">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="product-remove">&nbsp;</th>
                <th class="product-thumbnail">&nbsp;</th>
                <th class="product-name"><?php esc_html_e( 'Product', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
                <th class="product-price"><?php esc_html_e( 'Price', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
                <th class="product-quantity"><?php esc_html_e( 'Quantity', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
                <th class="product-subtotal"><?php esc_html_e( 'Subtotal', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart_contents' ); ?>

            <?php
            foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
                $_product   = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product', $cart_item['data'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
                $product_id = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product_id', $cart_item['product_id'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );

                if ( $_product && $_product->exists() && $cart_item['quantity'] > 0 && apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_visible', true, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) ) {
                    $product_permalink = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_permalink', $_product->is_visible() ? $_product->get_permalink( $cart_item ) : '', $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
                    ?>
            <?php if($cart_item['quantity'] == 2): ?>
                    <tr><td colspan="6">custom message</td></tr>
            <?php endif; ?>
                    <tr class="woocommerce-cart-form__cart-item <?php echo esc_attr( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_class', 'cart_item', $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) ); ?>">

                        <td class="product-remove">
                            <?php
                                echo apply_filters( // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped
                                    'woocommerce_cart_item_remove_link',
                                    sprintf(
                                        '<a href="%s" class="remove" aria-label="%s" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s">&times;</a>',
                                        esc_url( wc_get_cart_remove_url( $cart_item_key ) ),
                                        esc_html__( 'Remove this item', 'woocommerce' ),
                                        esc_attr( $product_id ),
                                        esc_attr( $_product->get_sku() )
                                    ),
                                    $cart_item_key
                                );
                            ?>
                        </td>

                        <td class="product-thumbnail">
                        <?php
                        $thumbnail = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_thumbnail', $_product->get_image(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );

                        if ( ! $product_permalink ) {
                            echo $thumbnail; // PHPCS: XSS ok.
                        } else {
                            printf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>', esc_url( $product_permalink ), $thumbnail ); // PHPCS: XSS ok.
                        }
                        ?>
                        </td>

                        <td class="product-name" data-title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Product', 'woocommerce' ); ?>">
                        <?php
                        if ( ! $product_permalink ) {
                            echo wp_kses_post( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', $_product->get_name(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) . '&nbsp;' );
                        } else {
                            echo wp_kses_post( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', sprintf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>', esc_url( $product_permalink ), $_product->get_name() ), $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) );
                        }

                        do_action( 'woocommerce_after_cart_item_name', $cart_item, $cart_item_key );

                        // Meta data.
                        echo wc_get_formatted_cart_item_data( $cart_item ); // PHPCS: XSS ok.

                        // Backorder notification.
                        if ( $_product->backorders_require_notification() && $_product->is_on_backorder( $cart_item['quantity'] ) ) {
                            echo wp_kses_post( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_backorder_notification', '<p class="backorder_notification">' . esc_html__( 'Available on backorder', 'woocommerce' ) . '</p>', $product_id ) );
                        }
                        ?>
                        </td>

                        <td class="product-price" data-title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Price', 'woocommerce' ); ?>">
                            <?php
                                echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_price', WC()->cart->get_product_price( $_product ), $cart_item, $cart_item_key ); // PHPCS: XSS ok.
                            ?>
                        </td>

                        <td class="product-quantity" data-title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Quantity', 'woocommerce' ); ?>">
                        <?php
                        if ( $_product->is_sold_individually() ) {
                            $product_quantity = sprintf( '1 <input type="hidden" name="cart[%s][qty]" value="1" />', $cart_item_key );
                        } else {
                            $product_quantity = woocommerce_quantity_input(
                                array(
                                    'input_name'   => "cart[{$cart_item_key}][qty]",
                                    'input_value'  => $cart_item['quantity'],
                                    'max_value'    => $_product->get_max_purchase_quantity(),
                                    'min_value'    => '0',
                                    'product_name' => $_product->get_name(),
                                ),
                                $_product,
                                false
                            );
                        }

                        echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_quantity', $product_quantity, $cart_item_key, $cart_item ); // PHPCS: XSS ok.
                        ?>
                        </td>

                        <td class="product-subtotal" data-title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Subtotal', 'woocommerce' ); ?>">
                            <?php
                                echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_subtotal', WC()->cart->get_product_subtotal( $_product, $cart_item['quantity'] ), $cart_item, $cart_item_key ); // PHPCS: XSS ok.
                            ?>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                }
            }
            ?>

            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_cart_contents' ); ?>

            <tr>
                <td colspan="6" class="actions">

                    <?php if ( wc_coupons_enabled() ) { ?>
                        <div class="coupon">
                            <label for="coupon_code"><?php esc_html_e( 'Coupon:', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label> <input type="text" name="coupon_code" class="input-text" id="coupon_code" value="" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Coupon code', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" /> <button type="submit" class="button" name="apply_coupon" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Apply coupon', 'woocommerce' ); ?>"><?php esc_attr_e( 'Apply coupon', 'woocommerce' ); ?></button>
                            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_cart_coupon' ); ?>
                        </div>
                    <?php } ?>

                    <button type="submit" class="button" name="update_cart" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Update cart', 'woocommerce' ); ?>"><?php esc_html_e( 'Update cart', 'woocommerce' ); ?></button>

                    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_cart_actions' ); ?>

                    <?php wp_nonce_field( 'woocommerce-cart', 'woocommerce-cart-nonce' ); ?>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_cart_contents' ); ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_cart_table' ); ?>
</form>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart_collaterals' ); ?>

<div class="cart-collaterals">
    <?php
        /**
         * Cart collaterals hook.
         *
         * @hooked woocommerce_cross_sell_display
         * @hooked woocommerce_cart_totals - 10
         */
        do_action( 'woocommerce_cart_collaterals' );
    ?>
</div>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_cart' ); ?>
```